# How to avoid output display at a specific moment of a PHP Unit test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, redirect, stdout

In a PHP unit test, for exemple :

```
class AgentBoardTest extends CommonTestCase
{
    /**
    * @test
    */
    public function display()
    {
        $very_long_string = "..................";
        echo $very_long_string;
    }
}
```

I don't want **$very_long_string** to be printed to stdout, especially when *echo* is done multiple times in multiple functions. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the best solution I found was to use PHP's native output buffering  :

```
class AgentBoardTest extends CommonTestCase
{
    /**
    * @test
    */
    public function display()
    {
        ob_start();

        $very_long_string = "..................";
        echo $very_long_string;

        ob_end_clean();
    }
}
```